# Checking equivalency of #t? (Scheme)

Tags: list, scheme

I have a functions that is called 'ordered'. Calling it with a list, it returns either #t or #f.

How could i check what the value it returns in an if statement outside of the function?
Right now i have:

```
(if (eqv? (ordered (car list)) '#t ))
```

Which doesn't really work.. 
How could i rewrite it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use

```
(if (ordered (car lst))
    ...)
```

In Scheme, the only false value is `#f`. Everything else is considered true.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Chris's answer, you don't have to check explicitly for `#t` equality. You can use the result of the procedure application directly in your `if`

```
(if (ordered (car list))
    "ordered returned true"
    "ordered returned non-true")
```

Or in `cond`

```
(cond [(ordered (car list)) "ordered returned true"]
      [else "ordered returned non-true"])
```

Also, it's conventional to suffix your procedure's name with `?` if it returns a boolean value

```
(define (ordered? list) ...)
```

That way, it's a little more readable and easy-to-understand in other parts of your code

```
(if (ordered? (car list)) ...)

(cond [(ordered? (car list)) ...]
      [else ...])
```